# Get the buttons from the SWT spinner widget

Tags: widget, swt, spinner

I'm in need of using a widget with the same functions as the buttons from the spinner widget. In other ways, i need a spinner without the text field. Is it possible to get the button only? I don't feel like writing my own widget due to portability issues.

peace,
Nik

Comment: Do you just want a button with an arrow on it or should it pop up a menu when you press on it?

Comment: Baz, what i want is a control that look exactly like the button the swt spinner uses (two small arrows one above the other) that wouldn't be platform specific (i do not want to implement my own control for different systems)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get anything from `Spinner`.

You can create a `Button` with an arrow style:

```
   Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.ARROW | SWT.UP);
```

(or `SWT.DOWN`, `SWT.LEFT`, `SWT.RIGHT`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like a control that look just like the spinner's set of buttons